# Is there any issue if I used sync connections in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I know that the pattern in iPhone is to use ASync connection calls (using the informal protocols that is implemented by the current class).

In my case, I've created a utility class to do the networking staff and then return the data to the ViewController.

I find is inadequate to implement the connection model as Async in a utility class because r I will write a block of code in the ViewControlle such following: (which IMHO is bad)

```
MyUtilityConnection* utilConn = ....
while (true)
{
    if ([utilConn checkUnderlyingAsyncConnectionFinishedLoading]) break;
}
NSData* dataFromUrl = [utilConn dataFromUnderlayingConn];
```

So, the question is, Does using Sync connection model in iPhone could causes problem? and solutions?

(What about the drawing will stril hanging until the data come???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AVOID** by all means to do synchronous connections! This will obviously freeze your UI (and it gets worse if you don't have a good bandwidth of course).

What you could do is to use the blocks syntax to write more readable code when you need to download data. Create a class that implements the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods, and then call the block when the data is done.

---

See my [OHURLLoader](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHURLLoader) class on github for example that does exactly that (and that's only one solution).

Usage example:

```
NSURL* url = ...
NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

OHURLLoader* loader = [OHURLLoader URLLoaderWithRequest:req];
[loader startRequestWithCompletion:^(NSData* receivedData, NSInteger httpStatusCode) {
    NSLog(@"Download of %@ done (statusCode:%d)",url,statusCode);
    outputTextView.text = loader.receivedString;
} errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error while downloading %@: %@",url,error);
    outputTextView.text = [error localizedDescription];
}];
```

Comment: What if I avoid using blocks (which I don't aware about) and uses regular selectors or even function pointers? so I'll have some thing like: in my ViewController I'd use `MyUtilityConnection util = [MyUtilityConnection utilConn] urlConn whenDonePerformSelector:@selector(some_local_method_in_the_viewController_calss)];` besides, I'll make the class `MyUtilityConnection` contains the async functions implemented and call the selector when data received?

Comment: That's also a possibility. You will have to provide both the target to call the selector onto and the selector itself as parameters, anyway. If you know about function pointers, you may be interested in learning about blocks: basically, blocks are quite the same as function pointers (and have a really similar syntax as it is inspired from them), but more powerful (especially they capture the variable of the enclosing scope — that's called a "closure").

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about blocks, [read the "Short Practical Guide to Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html) and [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) pages in Apple's documentation. _If you are confused with them, or intend to make your app compatible with iOS before 4.0, passing a target+selector to call on completion - instead of a block - is also good and totally acceptable, but a less "sexy" solution_ ;)

Comment: Thanks too much, really I read the wikipedia and few articles about blocks before, but since I am very new to Objc, I'd go the selector's way! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

During sync methods (`sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`) the UI is non-responsive (assuming that the sync method is called on the main thread).

But they are fine on background threads, the easiest way to accomplish sync calls on a background thread is with `GCD`.

Comment: Using GCD would work, sure, but as the Apple documentation states ([Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html)) if there is already an API provided by the SDK to perform the task asynchrnously (like using `NSURLConnection` asynchrnous methods) it is definitely better to use it. _(In this case NSURLConnection async methods avoids creating threads by internally scheduling the reading of socket data on the RunLoop)_